# 3D Rigid Body Physics (OpenGL)

Tags: c++, physics, rigid-bodies

I am trying to build rigid body physics engine. I am using the glm library as my standard math library.

The problems I am facing are as follows,

- When I calculate torque with respect to force (see function calculateTorque()), the body gets distorted and skewed to the extent, where it rotates and increases in size and is not visible anymore. But when I remove the force, from the torque equation that is I just randomize (see calculateForces())the torque values it works fine.
- When rotating, I think the body is skewing and increasing in size slightly, for both quaternions and matrices. (Not sure if the inertia calculation is right, the body is a cube)
- Am also having problems with the collision response, the body gradually penetrates the surface, and it does not react properly with respect to the value of epsilon.

P.S: The AABB - Plane collision is implemented with the help of the book Real Time Collision Detection by Christer Ericson, and the Rigid Body physics is implemented with the help of Braff's implementation.

Here is my code.

```
RigidBody::RigidBody(void)
{
}

RigidBody::RigidBody(float height, float width, float depth, int n)
    : height(height), width(width), depth(depth), nrb(n)
{
    objPos = new glm::vec3[n];
    worldPos = new glm::vec3[n];
    initRB();
}

RigidBody::~RigidBody(void)
{
}

void RigidBody::initRB()
{
    dt = 0.01;

    // Mass
    m = 0.5;
    float m_inverse = 1/m;

    // Inertia
    IBody = glm::mat3();
    IWorld = glm::mat3();

    IBody[0][0] = 1.0 / 12.0 * (m * ((height * height) + (depth * depth)));
    IBody[1][1] = 1.0 / 12.0 * (m * ((width * width) + (depth * depth)));
    IBody[2][2] = 1.0 / 12.0 * (m * ((width * width) + (height * height)));

    IBody_inverse = glm::inverse(IBody);

    // CG
    x = glm::vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

    // Linear Momentum
    P = glm::vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

    // Linear Velocity
    v = P * m_inverse;

    // Orientation (Matrix)
    R = glm::mat3();

    // Orientation (Quaternion)
    QR = glm::fquat();

    // Use Quaternion Flag
    useQuat = true;

    // Angular Velocity
    w = glm::vec3(1.0, 0.0, 1.0);

    // Angular Momentum
    L = IBody * w;

    // Forces
    rbPhys.gravitational = 9.81;
    rbPhys.viscousdrag = 0.1;
    f = glm::vec3(0.0, -m * rbPhys.gravitational, 0.0);

    // Torque
    t = glm::vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

    // Collision Flag
    collided = false;
}

void RigidBody::setBodyPos(glm::vec3 *verts)
{
    for(int i=0; i<nrb; i++)
    {
        objPos[i] = verts[i];
    }
}

void RigidBody::calculateBodyToWorld()
{
    for(int i=0; i<nrb; i++){
        worldPos[i] = R * objPos[i] + x;
    }
}

void RigidBody::calculateAABB()
{
    aabb.FindMaxMin(worldPos, nrb);
    max = aabb.GetMaxVertices();
    min = aabb.GetMinVertices();
}

glm::mat3 RigidBody::makeSkewSymmetric(glm::vec3 v)
{
    glm::mat3 result;

    result = glm::mat3(0.0, -v.z, v.y,
                       v.z, 0.0, -v.x,
                       -v.y, v.x, 0.0);

    return result;
}

glm::mat3 RigidBody::orthonormalize(glm::mat3 r)
{
    glm::mat3 result;

    glm::vec3 v1 = glm::vec3(r[0][0], r[1][0], r[2][0]);
    glm::vec3 v2 = glm::vec3(r[0][1], r[1][1], r[2][1]);
    glm::vec3 v3 = glm::vec3(r[0][2], r[1][2], r[2][2]);

    glm::normalize(v1);
    v2 = glm::cross(v3, v1);
    glm::normalize(v2);
    v3 = glm::cross(v1, v2);
    glm::normalize(v3);

    result[0][0] = v1.x;    result[0][1] = v2.x;    result[0][2] = v3.x;
    result[1][0] = v1.y;    result[1][1] = v2.y;    result[1][2] = v3.y;
    result[2][0] = v1.z;    result[2][1] = v2.z;    result[2][2] = v3.z;

    return result;
}

void RigidBody::computeAuxillary()
{
    // Linear Velocity
    float m_inverse = 1/m;
    v = P * m_inverse;

    // Inertia Tensor (World)
    IWorld = R * IBody * glm::transpose(R);
    IWorld_inverse = R * IBody_inverse * glm::transpose(R);     

    // Angular Velocity
    w = IWorld_inverse * L; 

    if(useQuat)
    {
        // Store quaternion in Rotation Matrix
        R = glm::mat3_cast(QR);
    }
}

void RigidBody::calculateForces()
{
    // sine torque to get some spinning action

    t.x = 1.0 * sin(dt*0.9 + 0.5);
    t.y = 1.1 * sin(dt*0.5 + 0.4);
    t.z = 1.2 * sin(dt*0.7 + 0.9);

    // damping torque so we dont spin too fast

    t.x -= 0.2 * w.x;
    t.y -= 0.2 * w.y;
    t.z -= 0.2 * w.z;
}

void RigidBody::calculateTorque()
{
    // Torque about a point p acted on by a force f
    // r = cg + R * p, here p is taken for granted as the center of the cube
    glm::vec3 r = glm::vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glm::vec3 p = glm::vec3(0.0, 0.5 * height, 0.0);
    r = x + (R * p);
    t = glm::cross((r - x),f);
}

void RigidBody::resetForces()
{
    f = glm::vec3(0.0, -m * rbPhys.gravitational, 0.0);
    t = glm::vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
}

void RigidBody::calculateDerivatives()
{
    rbDerivative.dvdt.x = v.x;
    rbDerivative.dvdt.y = v.y;
    rbDerivative.dvdt.z = v.z;

    if(useQuat)
    {
        glm::fquat wQ;
        wQ.w = 0;
        wQ.x = w.x;
        wQ.y = w.y;
        wQ.z = w.z;
        rbDerivative.dQRdt = glm::normalize(wQ * QR);
    }
    else
    {
        glm::mat3 wR = makeSkewSymmetric(w);
        rbDerivative.dRdt = wR * R;
    }

    rbDerivative.dPdt.x = f.x;
    rbDerivative.dPdt.y = f.y;
    rbDerivative.dPdt.z = f.z;

    rbDerivative.dLdt.x = t.x;
    rbDerivative.dLdt.y = t.y;
    rbDerivative.dLdt.z = t.z;
}

void RigidBody::updateRB()
{
    calculateForces();
    calculateDerivatives();

    x.x += rbDerivative.dvdt.x * dt;
    x.y += rbDerivative.dvdt.y * dt;
    x.z += rbDerivative.dvdt.z * dt;

    if(useQuat)
    {
        QR = QR + rbDerivative.dQRdt * dt;
    }
    else
    {
        R += rbDerivative.dRdt * dt;
        //R = orthonormalize(R); orthornormalize wrong
    }

    P.x += rbDerivative.dPdt.x * dt;
    P.y += rbDerivative.dPdt.y * dt;
    P.z += rbDerivative.dPdt.z * dt;

    L.x += rbDerivative.dLdt.x * dt;
    L.y += rbDerivative.dLdt.y * dt;
    L.z += rbDerivative.dLdt.z * dt;

    computeAuxillary();

    calculateAABB();
}

void RigidBody::renderRB()
{
    calculateBodyToWorld();

    glPushMatrix();
        glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        glBegin(GL_LINES);
            glVertex3f(max[0], max[1], max[2]);
            glVertex3f(max[0], min[1], max[2]);

            glVertex3f(max[0], max[1], max[2]);
            glVertex3f(min[0], max[1], max[2]); 

            glVertex3f(max[0], max[1], max[2]);
            glVertex3f(max[0], max[1], min[2]);

            glVertex3f(max[0], min[1], max[2]);
            glVertex3f(max[0], min[1], min[2]);

            glVertex3f(max[0], min[1], min[2]);
            glVertex3f(max[0], max[1], min[2]);

            glVertex3f(max[0], min[1], max[2]);
            glVertex3f(min[0], min[1], max[2]);

            glVertex3f(min[0], min[1], max[2]);
            glVertex3f(min[0], max[1], max[2]);

            glVertex3f(min[0], min[1], min[2]);
            glVertex3f(min[0], max[1], min[2]);

            glVertex3f(min[0], min[1], min[2]);
            glVertex3f(min[0], min[1], max[2]); 

            glVertex3f(min[0], min[1], min[2]);
            glVertex3f(max[0], min[1], min[2]);

            glVertex3f(min[0], max[1], min[2]);
            glVertex3f(max[0], max[1], min[2]);

            glVertex3f(min[0], max[1], min[2]);
            glVertex3f(min[0], max[1], max[2]);
        glEnd();

        if(isColliding())
            glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        else
            glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
            for(int i=0; i<nrb; i++)
            {
                glVertex3f(worldPos[i].x, worldPos[i].y, worldPos[i].z);
            }
        glEnd();
    glPopMatrix();
}

void RigidBody::printDebug()
{
    std::cout<<" "<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"RIGID BODY DEBUG:"<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"Height :"<<height<<" "<<"Width :"<<width<<" "<<"Depth :"<<depth<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<" "<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"Mass :"<<m<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<" "<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"Inverse Mass :"<<1/m<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<" "<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"CG :"<<x.x<<" "<<x.y<<" "<<x.z<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<" "<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"Linear Velocity :"<<v.x<<" "<<v.y<<" "<<v.z<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<" "<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"Linear Momentum :"<<P.x<<" "<<P.y<<" "<<P.z<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<" "<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"Angular Momentum :"<<L.x<<" "<<L.y<<" "<<L.z<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<" "<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"Angular Velocity :"<<w.x<<" "<<w.y<<" "<<w.z<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<" "<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"Torque :"<<t.x<<" "<<t.y<<" "<<t.z<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<" "<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"Force :"<<f.x<<" "<<f.y<<" "<<f.z<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<" "<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"Inertia Body:"<<IBody[0][0]<<" "<<IBody[0][1]<<" "<<IBody[0][2]<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"             "<<IBody[1][0]<<" "<<IBody[1][1]<<" "<<IBody[1][2]<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"             "<<IBody[2][0]<<" "<<IBody[2][1]<<" "<<IBody[2][2]<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<" "<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"Inertia Body (Inverse):"<<IBody_inverse[0][0]<<" "<<IBody_inverse[0][1]<<" "<<IBody_inverse[0][2]<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"                       "<<IBody_inverse[1][0]<<" "<<IBody_inverse[1][1]<<" "<<IBody_inverse[1][2]<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"                       "<<IBody_inverse[2][0]<<" "<<IBody_inverse[2][1]<<" "<<IBody_inverse[2][2]<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<" "<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"Inertia World:"<<IWorld[0][0]<<" "<<IWorld[0][1]<<" "<<IWorld[0][2]<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"              "<<IWorld[1][0]<<" "<<IWorld[1][1]<<" "<<IWorld[1][2]<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"              "<<IWorld[2][0]<<" "<<IWorld[2][1]<<" "<<IWorld[2][2]<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<" "<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"Inertia World (Inverse):"<<IWorld_inverse[0][0]<<" "<<IWorld_inverse[0][1]<<" "<<IWorld_inverse[0][2]<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"                        "<<IWorld_inverse[1][0]<<" "<<IWorld_inverse[1][1]<<" "<<IWorld_inverse[1][2]<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"                        "<<IWorld_inverse[2][0]<<" "<<IWorld_inverse[2][1]<<" "<<IWorld_inverse[2][2]<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<" "<<std::endl;  
    std::cout<<"Rotation (Matrix) :"<<R[0][0]<<" "<<R[0][1]<<" "<<R[0][2]<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"                 "<<R[1][0]<<" "<<R[1][1]<<" "<<R[1][2]<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"                 "<<R[2][0]<<" "<<R[2][1]<<" "<<R[2][2]<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<" "<<std::endl;
    if(useQuat)
    {
        std::cout<<"Rotation (Quaternion) :"<<QR.w<<" "<<QR.x<<" "<<QR.y<<" "<<QR.z<<std::endl;
    }
}   

bool AABB::IntersectsPlane(Plane p)
{
    glm::vec3 q;
    float t = 0.0;

    center = max + min;
    center /= 2.0;

    extents = max - center;

    glm::vec3 N = p.getPlaneNormal();

    float r = extents.x * abs(N.x) + extents.y * abs(N.y) + extents.z * abs(N.z);

    float d = glm::dot(N,center) - glm::dot(N,p.getVertex());

    if(abs(d) <= r)
    {
        t = 0.0;
        collisionPoint = center - r * N;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        if(glm::dot(N,p.getVertex()) >= 0.0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            float tempR = d > 0.0 ? r : -r;
            t = (tempR + d) - glm::dot(N,center) / glm::dot(N,p.getVertex());
            collisionPoint = center + t * p.getVertex()  - r * N;
            return true;
        }
    }
}

void CollisionManager::CheckPlaneRBCollision(RigidBody *rb, Plane *p, int n) 
{
    AABB aabb;
    glm::vec3 N;

    aabb = rb->aabb;

    for(int j=0; j<6; j++)
    {
        N = p[j].getPlaneNormal();

        if(aabb.IntersectsPlane(p[j]))
        {
            std::cout<<"Collision - Plane "<<j<<std::endl;
            rb->setCollisionFlag(true);
            rb->setCollisionPoint(aabb.GetAABBCollisionPoint());
            rb->setCollisionNormal(glm::normalize(rb->getCollisionPoint()));
            ApplyPlaneRBImpulse(rb);
        }
        else
        {
            rb->setCollisionFlag(false);
        }
    }
}

void CollisionManager::ApplyPlaneRBImpulse(RigidBody *rb)
{
    glm::vec3 j;
    glm::vec3 JN;

    float m_inverse = 1 / rb->getMass();
    glm::vec3 x = rb->getCG();
    glm::mat3 I_inv = rb->getInvInertiaWorldMat();
    glm::vec3 collP = rb->getCollisionPoint();
    glm::vec3 N = rb->getCollisionNormal(); 

    glm::vec3 pa = getCollisionPointVelocity(rb);
    glm::vec3 ra = collP - x;
    glm::vec3 vrel = N * pa;
    glm::vec3 numerator = -(1 + epsilon) * vrel;

    glm::vec3 term1 = glm::vec3(m_inverse, m_inverse, m_inverse);
    glm::vec3 term2 = N * (glm::cross(I_inv * glm::cross(ra,N),ra));
    glm::vec3 denominator = term1 + term2;

    j = numerator / denominator;

    JN = j * N;

    //std::cout<<"Impulse Vector "<<JN.x<<" "<<JN.y<<" "<<JN.z<<std::endl;

    // Apply Impulse
    glm::vec3 P = rb->getLMomentum();
    glm::vec3 L = rb->getAMomentum();

    P += JN;
    L += glm::cross(ra,JN);

    rb->setLMomentum(P);
    rb->setAMomentum(L);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From your description of the problem, it sounds like you are not normalizing whatever matrix or quaternion is representing the rotation of the rigid body.  You have a `orthonormalize()` function defined, but I see you commented out the code that calls it.  You will need to call that function and you will need to make it work, or else small numerical errors will build up and cause your object to grow as the matrix becomes further and further from being normal.

I don't know what the best way is to normalize a matrix, but my method (using the Eigen C++ library) used to work pretty well.  It went something like this:

```
matrix normalize(const matrix & matrix)
{
    matrix result;
    result.row(0) = matrix.row(0) + matrix.row(1).cross(matrix.row(2))/10;
    result.row(1) = matrix.row(1) + matrix.row(2).cross(matrix.row(0))/10;
    result.row(2) = matrix.row(2) + matrix.row(0).cross(matrix.row(1))/10;
    result.row(0).normalize();
    result.row(1).normalize();
    result.row(2).normalize();
    return result;
}
```

So you can convert that to GLM and try that, if your orthonormalize function isn't working.  The nice thing about mine is that it treats all axes equally, but the lame thing is it has this arbitrary number "10" which has no mathematical justification.  Also, the result will only be approximately orthonormal, but if your incremental rotations are small enough and you call this function after each rotation that shouldn't be a problem.

(In my project, I switched over to using quaternions and got rid of this function.)

Comment: I see what your saying about the rotation matrix, but the skewing and size problem happens even when I use quaternions. When using quaternions, I store the quaternion as a 3 X 3 matrix for the purpose of calculating Inertia Tensor.

Comment: I haven't looked at your code carefully enough, but are you actually normalizing the quaternions?  Also, storing a quaternion as a 3x3 matrix doesn't make sense to me.  Either your store a quaternion (4 numbers) or you store a matrix (9 numbers).

Comment: Maybe storing it as a 3 X 3 matrix is the problem. Why does that seem wrong to you? I have never really used quaternions before.

Comment: A quaternion is 4 numbers, a matrix is 9 numbers.  Either you store a quaternion or you store a matrix.  They are two different ways to represent a rotation. It doesn't make sense to say you are storing a quaternion as a matrix.  It could make sense to say you are storing the rotation as a matrix, and converting to quaternions at some point, and then converting quaternions to matrices at some point.

Comment: Well that is not the problem, just checked it, still doesn't work. I am normalizing the quaternion, and casting it appropriately when calculating inertia.

Comment: Do you notice anything wrong with the collision part? Specifically the collision response?